# Adding of license data to winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, license-key

I'm trying to figure out what is a proper way adding of license  text or related document data inside application build.

As example I found [this answer about getting of specific type of license for using of CV library](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18421), but there is no single explanation, what should I do after getting of this or any other license with information document. Where do I have to add it, inside application as a `.txt` document, into installer confirmation or just keep it in table. I'm trying to figure out, how to make this addition technically and correct way

Comment: That depends entirely on how you want to use it and what the license requirements are. There’s no one single way to do it.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen Hello, well, would be very useful, if you can provide basic technical ways for how license data can be added to application build, even if there is a different using cases. As I understand, there is a two ways, one which represents software status, and mostly appears in installer confirmation, another included inside build, for example in case of CV example as above I guess, but I'm not sure,  or library examples. Anyway, both variants are interesting is my case, but I'm not sure about physical adding method at all